# Spawn child console/cmd.exe inside existing console/cmd.exe without a new window

Tags: c#, cmd, console, console-application, windows-console

I would like to spawn a console with different env variables (e.g. PATH or PROMPT) *inside* an already running console. I would also like to be able to "exit-back" to the original console via "exit" (this is not that important).

The code below works fine, but it opens a new console window.

If i remove the FreeConsole()-call, the new console is inside the existing one, but after every enter keypress i end up back in the parent console (it switches back and forth between the two consoles).

Something like this:

```
CHILD_CONSOLE
D:\dev\>
CHILD_CONSOLE
D:\dev\>
CHILD_CONSOLE
...
```

AttachConsole() and AllocConsole() also did not work.

I could probably simulate the console and pass the input/output streams back and forth, but that seems way to complex...

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool FreeConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

// ...

public void SpawnConsole()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe ";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PROMPT"] = "CHILD_CONSOLE ";
    // set some more env variable on process...
    FreeConsole();
    process.Start();
}
```

Updated the question with the most minimal demo app:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool FreeConsole();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe ";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PROMPT"] = "CHILD_CONSOLE ";
            // Works with this, but then a new prompt window is openend
            // FreeConsole();
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For all your child consoles, instead of spawning a new process, tell your existing console to run another copy of cmd.

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail? How can i start another cmd.exe without using a new process?

Comment: You would need to feed it keystrokes. What is your first console doing?

Comment: The parent console is just a cmd.exe prompt. From there i just call my c# console app, e.g. "myapp newcmd". This should then start the new cmd.exe (with another PATH/PROMPT) inside the existing console (not a new window, that already works fine).

Comment: If you don't use the "start" command to start myapp separately, the console will be waiting for myapp to close and will not process any commands until myapp closes.

Comment: Since i probably did not make my question clear enough i just added a simple demo app.